# Getting extreme execution time difference between EF and SSMS

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2019

I am trying to run a stored procedure from EF6 using `Database.SqlQuery`. It executes, that's true, but with inexplicably long execution time (even 100-200s). The same statement is blazing fast in SSMS (I have copied the statement from the profiler to have them completely matching). The example from below yields no actual result rows thus no data transfer can affect the execution.

[image]

The number of reads and writes is also by several magnitudes larger when executed from code. The mapped type is POCO, with plain properties. Nothing else is using the database and I have also wrapped the execution in a ReadUncommitted transaction to avoid any kind of lock - no effect.

What can cause this?

Comment: Is that with the exact same parameters? (value and data types) Could there be any implicit data type conversions between C#/EF execution and what the Stored Procedure expects?

Comment: The query plans must be different. See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).